# Set display font family in wxhaskell?

Tags: haskell, wxhaskell

I'm trying to build a little program to learn some wxHaskell, a haskell library for wxwidgets.

It would be beneficial for this particular one if I could set the font of a text field to monospaced, but I have no idea how to do that if it is possible.

In wxwidgets there seems to be `setFamily` and `wxFONTFAMILY_TELETYPE`, but I can't find anything about this being implemented in wxHaskell, nor how to use it if it were.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, in the change the line in the [Hello, World program in the wxHaskell Quick Start](https://wiki.haskell.org/WxHaskell/Quick_start) from:

```
  = do f    <- frame    [text := "Hello!"]
```

to

```
  = do f    <- frame    [text := "Hello!", font := fontFixed]
```

Found this by digging down in the [docs here](https://github.com/wxHaskell/wxHaskell/blob/master/wxcore/src/haskell/Graphics/UI/WXCore/Draw.hs#L195)